# Lazy Loading on a List of Objects using Java?

Tags: java, gwt, lazy-loading

I am using Java and GWT. I have a list of objects that loads dynamically (onPageLoad) and I want to show this list of objects using lazy loading. I don't know if there is such GWT component, or I have to use some js plug-in. I checked this post: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload but it looks like it is only for objects (imgs) that are hard-coded. What/where should I look for such plug-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a plugin or a component. You simply attach an event handler to a widget that triggers additional loading requests. It can be a ScrollPanel if you lazy load on scroll down, or a Button/Label (e.g. "Show more"), etc. When this event is triggered, you load and display more objects.